# return an attribute of the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

```
<a href="#" ngclick="changePredicate(\'data.X\')"ng:class="selectedCls(\'data.X\')">  {{data.X}}</a>\

scope.datas = [{ id: "1", name: "Moroni", startDate: '01/01/2012', homeLocation: "Houston"},
               { id: "2", name: "Dupont", startDate: '01/05/2011', homeLocation: "Johan"}];
```

I need to to get the attributes of my array (`id`, `name`, `homeLocation`) from the table
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
{{ datas[0].id }}
```

Remember, whatever's in the brackets is just JavaScript.

Alternatively, you could use [`ng-repeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

```
<div ng-repeat="datum in datas">
  {{ datum.id }}
  {{ datum.name }}
  {{ datum.homeLocation }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi..Maybe I want to have back the attributes names and not the values

Comment: in your solution {{ datum.id }} return the the values of the id and I want just to render id my html